# MySQL group rows by progressive date in consecutive rows

Tags: mysql

This is my table

```
+------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ID_1 | ID_2 | ID_3 |        enter        |        exit         |
+------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | A    | I    | 17/01/2013 15:37:25 | 18/01/2013 16:26:47 |
|    1 | A    | I    | 18/01/2013 16:26:47 | 28/01/2013 11:22:59 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 13/06/2013 22:23:54 | 21/06/2013 16:45:37 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 21/06/2013 16:45:37 | 23/06/2013 09:45:00 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 23/06/2013 09:45:00 | 23/06/2013 11:57:18 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 23/06/2013 11:57:18 | 25/06/2013 13:35:51 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 25/06/2013 14:45:21 | 25/06/2013 17:57:03 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 25/06/2013 17:57:03 | 28/06/2013 09:45:00 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 28/06/2013 09:45:00 | 28/06/2013 12:41:28 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 28/06/2013 12:41:28 | 03/07/2013 20:19:29 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 03/07/2013 20:19:29 | 05/07/2013 17:11:30 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 05/07/2013 21:33:30 | 10/07/2013 10:55:38 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 10/07/2013 13:29:58 | 09/08/2013 17:16:13 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 09/08/2013 17:16:13 | 27/09/2013 14:45:31 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 27/09/2013 14:45:31 | 11/11/2013 12:00:00 |
|    1 | C    | III  | 09/03/2014 00:14:31 | 05/04/2014 12:12:51 |
+------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

My aim is to group rows by ID_1, ID_2, ID_3 when `exit` of previous row is equal to `enter` of next row, and I also want to change `exit` with the the last consecutive `exit` The resul should be

```
+------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ID_1 | ID_2 | ID_3 |        enter        |        exit         |
+------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | A    | I    | 17/01/2013 15:37:25 | 28/01/2013 11:22:59 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 13/06/2013 22:23:54 | 25/06/2013 13:35:51 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 25/06/2013 14:45:21 | 05/07/2013 17:11:30 |
|    1 | B    | II   | 05/07/2013 21:33:30 | 11/11/2013 12:00:00 |
|    1 | C    | III  | 09/03/2014 00:14:31 | 05/04/2014 12:12:51 |
+------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Is it possible to have it in MySQL?

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? Is there any Primary key in your table ? Without that we really cant define "order", as data is unordered

Comment: This looks like a gaps and islands problem to me, or at least a variant of it.  If you are using MySQL 8+ or later, then you may take advantage of analytic functions, which would really help here.

Comment: MySQL 5.7. There is no pk in my table

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If you have no PK, then you have no table.

Comment: It seems to me that it would be possible to not define a PK and ORDER BY `enter`. Having said that, I do like a surrogate key.. fairly sure MySQL generates a behind the scenes equivalent if you don't define a PK.

Comment: @Arth It depends on the engine (I think)

Comment: @Strawberry, ah yes, good point.. I was thinking of innoDB. [Latest Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html)